# Field not found: SETFILTER

Tags: clarion

I am currently getting the Clarion 6.3 error: `Field not found: SETFILTER`

The code is located in the ApplyFilter section which is part of the ObjectABC template code below:

```
If g:InstallerIsRegional = 1
    localVar:ItemCode = IWIE:InvItemCode !Store itemCode from view
    GetRegionalItemPrice(localVar:ItemCode ) !Proc to check if Itemcode to be included in browse.
End
INVWIMEX.SetFilter('IWIE:InvItemCode[1]='''&localVar:ItemCode[1]&'''')
INVWIMEX.ApplyFilter
INVWIMEX.Next()
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some unbalanced quotes.

Try this:

```
strFilter = 'IWIE:InvItemCode[1]=<39>' & localVar:ItemCode[1] &'<39>'
INVWIMEX.SetFilter(strFilter)
```

PS: add this to the data section: strFilter string(255)

Comment: It's kind of interesting that this compiles:
`'IWIE:InvItemCode[1]=''' & pasConfig.TerminalName & ''''`
but this does not, just adding spaces to show the unbalanced quotes:
`'IWIE:InvItemCode[1]=' '' & pasConfig.TerminalName & '' ''`